# Merged cells extraction using Python from word document

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, extract

I am trying to extract table and its contents from a word document, so far, using the docx library I was able to extract table and store it in an excel sheet, but if there are merged cells in the table, then I am only getting the last entry.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?[image: The input table looks something like this]

[image: The output that I am getting-Column3 and Column4 are not extracted as they are, instead I am getting a single cell value(last entry)]

The solution I am using

```
from docx.api import Document
path="path"
document= Document(path)
output_path = "output_path"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('{}/docx_tables.xlsx'.format(output_path),engine='xlsxwriter')
for i in range(len(document.tables)):
    table = document.tables[i]
    data=[]
    keys=None
    row_data = None
    for j,row in enumerate(table.rows):
        text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        if j ==0:
           keys = tuple(text)
           continue
        row_data = dict(zip(keys,text))
        data.append(row_data)
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
 df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='table_{}'.format(i))
writer.save()
```